# Laravel - Missing required parameters for [Route: tarjeta.destroy]

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Tengo este form :

```
   <form action="{{route('tarjeta.destroy',$tarjeta)}}" method="POST">
                                @csrf
                                @method('delete')
                                <input  type="text" {{$tarjeta->id}}>
                                <button class="underline text-white-100 bg-red-300" href="{{route('tarjeta.destroy')}}">Eliminar</button>

                        </form>
```

La ruta es resource :

```
 Route::resource('tarjeta', TarjetaController::class);
```

El valor **$tarjeta** existe, eso no es el problema.
Pero por algun motivo no le gusta que le pase ese objeto.

---

Esto sale con el comando **php artisan route:list** :

```
   +--------+-----------+-------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
    | Domain | Method    | URI                     | Name             | Action                                                                 | Middleware |
    +--------+-----------+-------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
    |        | GET|HEAD  | /                       |                  | Closure                                                                | web        |
    |        |           |                         |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | api/user                |                  | Closure                                                                | api        |
    |        |           |                         |                  |                                                                        | auth:api   |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | home                    | home             | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | web        |
    |        |           |                         |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | login                   | login            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web        |
    |        |           |                         |                  |                                                                        | guest      |
    |        | POST      | login                   |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web        |
    |        |           |                         |                  |                                                                        | guest      |
    |        | POST      | logout                  | logout           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web        |
    |        | POST      | password/confirm        |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@confirm            | web        |
    |        |           |                         |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | password/confirm        | password.confirm | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@showConfirmForm    | web        |
    |        |           |                         |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
    |        | POST      | password/email          | password.email   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web        |
    |        | POST      | password/reset          | password.update  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web        |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset          | password.request | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web        |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset/{token}  | password.reset   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web        |
    |        | POST      | register                |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web        |
    |        |           |                         |                  |                                                                        | guest      |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | register                | register         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web        |
    |        |           |                         |                  |                                                                        | guest      |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | tarjeta                 | tarjeta.index    | App\Http\Controllers\TarjetaController@index                           | web        |
    |        |           |                         |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
    |        | POST      | tarjeta                 | tarjeta.store    | App\Http\Controllers\TarjetaController@store                           | web        |
    |        |           |                         |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | tarjeta/create          | tarjeta.create   | App\Http\Controllers\TarjetaController@create                          | web        |
    |        |           |                         |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | tarjeta/{tarjetum}      | tarjeta.show     | App\Http\Controllers\TarjetaController@show                            | web        |
    |        |           |                         |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
    |        | PUT|PATCH | tarjeta/{tarjetum}      | tarjeta.update   | App\Http\Controllers\TarjetaController@update                          | web        |
    |        |           |                         |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
    |        | DELETE    | tarjeta/{tarjetum}      | tarjeta.destroy  | App\Http\Controllers\TarjetaController@destroy                         | web        |
    |        |           |                         |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | tarjeta/{tarjetum}/edit | tarjeta.edit     | App\Http\Controllers\TarjetaController@edit                            | web        |
    |        |           |                         |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
    +--------+-----------+-------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

------------+

Metodo del controlador: (esta vacio aun ) :

```
/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  \App\Models\Tarjeta  $tarjeta
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy(Tarjeta $tarjeta)
{
    //
}
```

Comment: Ejecuta en la consola `php artisan route:list`, desplazate hasta la la ruta que identifica la eliminación y verifica como esta constituida, de preferencia edita tu pregunta y agrega aqui como aparece ahi dicha ruta

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta con lo que me habeis dicho.

Answer (score 1):

como vi que nadie respondió espero le pueda ayudar a alguien mas:

```
   <form action="{{route('tarjeta.destroy',$tarjeta->id)}}" method="POST">
                            @csrf
                            @method('delete')
                            <input  type="text" {{$tarjeta->id}}>
                            <button class="underline text-white-100 bg-red-300" href="{{route('tarjeta.destroy')}}">Eliminar</button>

                    </form>
```

Te falto agregarle el "->id" a $tarjeta en el TAG form.